# Ошибка local variable 'd' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

у меня ошибка (строчка 15): `local variable 'd' referenced before assignment`
Но бага не вижу. Прикрепляю код программы:

```
from fractions import gcd
N = int(input())
x = 5
y = 1
i = 0
z = 2
def f(N,x,y,i,z):
    while gcd(N, abs(x - y)) == 1:
        if i == z:
            y = x
            z = z**2
        x = (x**2 - 1) // N
        i += 1
        d = gcd(N, abs(x - y))
    if d == 1:
        return d
    else:
        return f(N/d,x,y,i,z)
print(f(N,x,y,i,z))
```

Программа должна факторизовать вводимое число.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у вас цикл while ни разу не выполняется, (я проверил на N=34) соответственно при попытке выполнить  if d == 1: переменная d не определена.
Вердикт - выясняйте, почему условие gcd(N, abs(x - y)) == 1  не выполняется.